# How can I change color and cell height only for a single row?

Tags: tables

I'm trying to make a LaTeX table on this way: the first row needs to have bigger height than the others (like 1.5 times) and it needs to be gray. I have thought to solve it with the command written below (\rule and \vspace). But the problem is that the row is no fully coloured. What should I improve to solve it correctly? Thank you in advance.

```latex
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{TableName}
\begin{tabular}{lcc}

\hline \hline
\rule{0pt}{1.25em} \rowcolor{gray!15}
\vspace {0.25em}
\rowcolor{gray!15} Tiempo (s) & Amplitud  & ln (ampl/ampl.inicial) \\ \hline
0 & 18 & 0 \\
4,51 & 16,8 & -0,068992871 \\ 
9,95 & 15,8 & -0,130361818 \\ 
15,13 & 14,8 & -0,195744577 \\ 
20,32 & 13,8 & -0,265703166 \\ 
25,42 & 12,6 & -0,356674944 \\ 
30,51 & 11,6 & -0,43936666 \\ 
35,67 & 10,8 & -0,510825624 \\ \hline \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a full compilable code?

Answer (score 1):

A possibility. I added some improvements (using the `S` column type from `siunitx` and loading `caption` for a decant spacing between caption above and table). The first cell height is changed vis the `\Gape` command from `makecell`. Do not forget  that `\rowcolor` has to be the first command at the beginning of the row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell, caption}
\captionsetup{skip=4pt}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\sisetup{copy-decimal-marker}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\caption{TableName}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=2.3, table-number-alignment=left]S[table-format=2.1]S[table-format=-1.9]}
\hline \hline
\rowcolor{gray!15}{\Gape[18pt][12pt]{} Tiempo (s)} &{ Amplitud}& {ln(ampl/ampl.inicial)} \\ \hline
0 & 18 & 0 \\
4,51 & 16,8 & -0,068992871 \\
9,95 & 15,8 & -0,130361818 \\
15,13 & 14,8 & -0,195744577 \\
20,32 & 13,8 & -0,265703166 \\
25,42 & 12,6 & -0,356674944 \\
30,51 & 11,6 & -0,43936666 \\
35,67 & 10,8 & -0,510825624 \\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]